# How to run commands locally even when on tramp?

Tags: tramp, shell-command

I have some commands that do "utility" stuff that have nothing to do with the current buffer. I need these to always run locally, and not remotely when visiting a tramp buffer. How can I do this?

Here is the function in question:

```lisp
(if load-file-name
    (setq night/fzf-cmd (concat (file-name-directory load-file-name) "/fzf_in2.dash")))

(defun night/helper-counsel-fzf-entries (str)
  (let ((entries night/counsel--fzf-entries))
    (setq ivy--old-re (ivy--regex-fuzzy str))
    (let ((night/counsel--stdin (mapconcat (lambda (x) x) entries "\n")))
      (f-write-text night/counsel--stdin 'utf-8 "/tmp/nightFzf.txt")
      (counsel--async-command
       (list night/fzf-cmd "-f" str)
       )))
  nil)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is `default-directory`. If it is local, your command runs locally. So do something like

```
(let ((default-directory "/"))
  (do your stuff))
```

Comment: Would `"/"` be a good choice? Would it not affect performance? (Because `/` is a big crowded directory.)

Comment: I haven't seen such performance penalties yet, but of course it is up to your taste. You can use any directory guaranteed to be local, like `temporary-file-directory` or `user-emacs-directory`.